# col-md-3 is not positioning to the right of col-md-9 - what are the factors that occuring the incident?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

[image]In my website output - **Col-md-9** is running perfectly - while **col-md-3** moves down to **col-md-9**, having all the necessary properties put correctly.

`<?php get_header(); ?>`

`col-md-9`

```
    <div class="col-md-9">

      <?php 
      if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
      ?>

      <div class="blog_area">
        <div class="post_thumb">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails'); ?></a>
          
        </div>
        <div class="post_details">
          <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        </div>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      </div>

        <?php 
         endwhile;
        else:
          _e('No post found');
        endif;
        ?>

        <div id="pagination">
          <?php if('bobcat_pagination') {bobcat_pagination(); } else{ ?>
          <?php next_post_link(); ?>
          <?php previous_post_link(); ?>
        <?php } ?> 
        </div>

       
        

    </div>
```

[image]

`col-md-3`

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
type here
```

`

`note`
Here, how the sidebar apperaing in the entire web pages -other than Blog Page.

If you need more of coding snippets or clues, I will provide you.

Comment: Fotunately and finally - I found the issue that causing the problem I stated above and wrapping the thread at this point. The probelm was with the pagination div that was unfortunaly convoluted in col-md-9 div.